# getConnection null in new transaction

Tags: ejb-3.0, weblogic, datasource, jndi

I am using Weblogic 11, ejb3.0

I have code which is doing lookup to another deployment in my container remotely.
everything work fine and I managed to reach to the another deployment.
the method which working in the remote deployment open new transaction via the annotation:

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)

and when it finish and get back to my deployment I have weird situation which I can get connection from my data source using the method databseDataSource.getConnection();
(It receives null)

I am using XA.

any ideas why?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that we cant open new transaction when combining  xa and non xa datasources.
I have moved everything to xa and it worked right